# Loading images issue with jQuery and/or image slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On my site I found strange bug - CoinSlider ( vSlider for Wordpress ) is loading image from server on every(!) slide change ( you can check that with dev tools in Chrome for example ). What may it be?

Target site - http://sytyi-drakon.ru/ ( slider in header )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's wrong with the header again? i totally dont get this.

Comment: jquery image slider in header loads image from server every time on slide animation ( you can see that animation too slow )

Comment: http://www.picamatic.com/view/9567498_Voila_Capture17/ - Chrome stats screenshot